# Listagem em laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Olá,
Tenho seguinte modelagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Uma tabela treinos que tem varios modelos de treinos (modelos_treinos).
A tabela modelos_treinos tem varios exercicios.
No laravel, eu preciso listar um determinado treino (id 1, por exemplo), todos os modelos desse treino e todos os exercicios desse modelo.
No código abaixo, eu conseguir trazer os dados do treino e os modelos de treino, porém não conseguir trazer os exercicios e seus dados:

```
$trainings = TrainingHasModels::with(['models' => function($query){
        $query
        ->get()
        ->first();
     }])
     ->where('training_id', $training->id)
     ->get();
```

Model Training

```
public function trainingStudentExercises()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\TrainingStudentExercise','training_id'); 
}
```

Model TrainingModel

```
public function trainingExercises()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\TrainingExercise','training_model_id'); 
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mostre como está o código do Model de _treinos_ e o Model de _modelos_treinos_

Comment: Coloque também as classes model

Comment: Editei a pergunta com os módulos